# Views Drupal Clone

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views

I've purchased a theme which turned out to not being well documented or supported and after almost completing my website I came across a problem that I can't solve :(

I should start saying that I'm a newbie and this is probably really easy but I can't seem to find the answer.

I created a clone of a view which has a really nice style to it:

http://www.calaverastattoo.com/portfolio/category/

and my clone looks like this:

http://www.calaverastattoo.com/portfolio/category/angel

If someone has an idea of how to fix this I'd really appreciate your help.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

It is probably because of missing CSS styling. Make sure to copy the required CSS code in the  new theme.

Comment: Hi Muhammad, is that CSS inside of the view? or on a folder as Daniel suggests? thank you

Comment: There is a section on the view that says CSS Lass but the value is "None"

Comment: Insert the required CSS in your template's CSS file.

Answer (score 1):

You need to duplicate the following files and put them in the same folder location as the originals.

So for example /sites/all/themes/YOURTHEME/templates (This is a guess) will contain the following files. I think angel is the name of your new view?

original  - views-view-fields--portfolio--page.tpl.php
duplicate - views-view-fields--angel--page.tpl.php

original  - views-view-fields--portfolio--items-summary.tpl.php
duplicate - views-view-fields--angel--items-summary.tpl.php

original  - views-view-fields--portfolio--items-summary.tpl.php
duplicate - views-view-fields--angel--items-summary.tpl.php

original  - views-view-unformatted--portfolio--items-summary.tpl.php
duplicate - views-view-unformatted--angel--items-summary.tpl.php

original  - views-view-unformatted--portfolio--page.tpl.php
duplicate - views-view-unformatted--angel--page.tpl.php

original  - views-view-unformatted--portfolio--page.tpl.php
duplicate - views-view-unformatted--angel--page.tpl.php

As this is a custom theme you have bought I'm not 100% of how it loads the template files the above example would work with most drupal base themes.

Cheers Dan

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that the view that comes with template you have bought has it's own template which will be a file in the theme directory called something like this (possibly in a directory called tempaltes)

views-view-page--portfolio--portfolio.tpl.php

If you edit the original view look in the bottom right hand corner of the page there is an option called theme with a link called information. Click Information and it shows you which templates files will affect that view.

Thanks

Comment: Hi Daniel, you are right I found the folder you are talking about and it contains the following files: views-view-fields--portfolio--page.tpl.php ........... views-view-fields--portfolio--items-summary.tpl.php .........  views-view-unformatted--portfolio--items-summary.tpl.php .........  views-view-unformatted--portfolio--page.tpl.php

Comment: I copied the whole folder "portfolio-category-view" and rename it to "portfolio-category-angel-view" but still not working am I doing something wrong? (probably everything!) Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Ok so you need to check in the bottom right hand corner of your angels view at "Theme Information" clicking this will tell you which templates will override the view. I've added another answer.